# How to rename uploaded files asp.net core mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, upload, asp.net-core-mvc, rename

i had created an upload link like this
[image]
Here was my code in the controller

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index(ICollection<IFormFile> files)
    {
        var uploads = Path.Combine(_environment.WebRootPath, "UploadedFiles/Archives");
        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            if (file.Length > 0)
            {

                using (var fileStream = new FileStream(Path.Combine(uploads, file.FileName), FileMode.Create))
                {
                    await file.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
                }
            }
        }
        return View();
    }
```

it save the files inside with the name user defined. like the "Alumni Survey.pdf"[image]

i want to rename the "Alumni Survey.pdf" to "2017.pdf" how can i do that?
besides i want to limit the user only can upload .pdf files, what should i search for it?

Comment: Concerning the naming. Just do not use the `file.FileName` and name it what ever you want

Comment: Do you understand your own code? You're passing a filename to the `FileStream`.  Just pass a different filename.

Comment: i had find my solution, such a noob question here,. thanks for reply

Comment: if i want to generate the new folder under the Archives folder, how should i do it?

Comment: @EmilyGermanotta and for the file limitation use the `accept` attribute in the file input tag `accept="application/pdf"`

Comment: that works. thanks Nkosi

Comment: Try `Directory.Create()`.

Comment: @EmilyGermanotta you need to clarify the question with a [mcve]  so that a proper answer can be provided.

Comment: @Nkosi yes sure.

Answer (score 3):

> i want to rename the "Alumni Survey.pdf" to "2017.pdf" how can i do that?

Just do not use the `file.FileName` and name it what ever you want.

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Index(ICollection<IFormFile> files) {
    var uploads = Path.Combine(_environment.WebRootPath, "UploadedFiles/Archives");
    foreach (var file in files) {
        if (file.Length > 0) {
            using (var fileStream = new FileStream(Path.Combine(uploads, "<My file name here>"), FileMode.Create)) {
                await file.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
            }
        }
    }
    return View();
}
```

Do note that as you have a collection of files you will need to cater for multiple files in the upload when naming them. Can't name them all the same.

> i want to limit the user only can upload .pdf files,

for the file limitation use the `accept` attribute in the file input tag `accept="application/pdf"`

```
<input type="file" 
       class="form-control" 
       id="files" 
       name="files"
       accept="application/pdf">
```

Comment: the other question was i now needed two forms which are using the same controller index() function, how i know which form is calling?

Comment: Add a property/field/form-value in a hidden input that you can check in the action to know when form sent it. You are now adding additional requirements to the OP. do not do that. If you have new questions then create new question.

Answer (score 2):

to rename the file use **Move** as given below. For oldFilePath and newFilePath put your previous file path and the file path with the new file name to be changed.

```
 System.IO.File.Move(oldFilePath, newFilePath);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    public IActionResult FileUpload()
    {
        try
        {
            var file = Request.Form.Files[0];
            var folderName = Path.Combine("Resources", "Files");
            var pathToSave = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), folderName);

            if (file.Length > 0)
            {
                var fileName = ContentDispositionHeaderValue.Parse(file.ContentDisposition).FileName.Trim('"');
                //var fullPath = Path.Combine(pathToSave, fileName);
                string renameFile = Convert.ToString(Guid.NewGuid()) + "." + fileName.Split('.').Last();
                var fullPath = Path.Combine(pathToSave, renameFile);
                var dbPath = Path.Combine(folderName, fileName);

                using (var stream = new FileStream(fullPath, FileMode.Create))
                {
                    file.CopyTo(stream);
                }
                return Ok(new { renameFile });
            }
            else
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return StatusCode(500, "Internal server error");
        }
    }`
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Guid` to give your file a unique name. This unique name is different every time.

```
     [HttpPost]
            public async Task<IActionResult> Index(ICollection<IFormFile> files)
            {
                var uploads = Path.Combine(_environment.WebRootPath, "UploadedFiles/Archives");
                
                foreach (var file in files)
                {
                    if (file.Length > 0)
                    {
var uniqueFileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);
                        using (var fileStream = new FileStream(Path.Combine(uploads, uniqueFileName), FileMode.Create))
                        {
                            await file.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
                        }
                    }
                }
                return View();
}
```

And for limiting the user's file input to pdfs only
In View:

```
<input type="file" name="files" id="files" class="form-control" accept="application/pdf" multiple />
```